# findPlaceFromQuery return bad `PlacesServiceStatus`

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I followed the code example for the findPlaceFromQuery() method from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query.

I have the exact code for the query part. However, the `PlacesServiceStatus` returned is always not OK. I tried changing the `query` value in the `request` object but the result is always the same.

Any idea why this is happening?

I'm pasting the relevant code snippet below for easy reference. It's mostly the same as the sample code. I just added the `else` clause at the end:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8617374,151.2021291);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: mapCenter,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    query: 'Museum of Contemporary Art Australia',
    fields: ['photos', 'formatted_address', 'name', 'rating', 'opening_hours', 'geometry'],

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
  else{
      alert("status bad");
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working now for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of prerequests that people need to be aware of for this code to work. For the places API request to work the following action must be performed:

1. The places library must be added explicity from the calling method like so `&libraries=places`. This is because the places API doesn't come as standard with the maps API.

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY& libraries=places&callback=YOUR_CALLBACK_METHOD"></script>`

2. The API key used must have the right places credentials from the google console. This [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key) exaplains how this can be done.